# How to lock bootloader with stock os in moto e2?

Tags: motorola-moto-e

I have asked my to install custom rom. He unloacked the bootloader and installed custom rom.
After installed, my speakers and calling features are not worked.

I thought the problem is with custom rom. So I have thought to install the stock os again.

But I don't know how to install.
Can anyone please help me how to install the stock os and lock the bootloader again?

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstalling the stock rom will not give you a locked bootloader. You will need to factory restart the phone by either going into the settings on the phone, or connecting it to a computer and using a utility there to factory reset.

Comment: The part about bootloader is correct; however, factory reset will not remove the custom ROM. OP, you should just flash another custom ROM that's verified compatible with your specific variant (Moto E2 has multiple variants with minor differences).

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest any stable custom rom?